# Enum type reference or primitive (with example) - shallow/deep copy

Tags: java, enums, deep-copy, shallow-copy

My question is very basic, but I would like to understand everything in 100%. Many questions in SO referes to my post, but I haven't find a satisfying answer.

We know that Enums in java are reference type. Let's consider the following snippet:

```
public static class A {
    public int i;
    public A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public static class Test {
    int i;
    A a;

    public Test(int i, A a){
        this.i = i;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Test(Test oldTest){
        this.i = oldTest.i;
        this.a = oldTest.a;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t1 = new Test(10, new A(100));
    System.out.println(t1.i + " " + t1.a.i);
    Test t2 = new Test(t1);
    t2.i = 200;
    t2.a.i = 3983;
    System.out.println(t2.i + " " + t2.a.i);
    System.out.println(t1.i + " " + t1.a.i);

}
```

Output is quite obvious because copy constructor of Test makes a shallow copy:

```
10 100
200 3983
10 3983
```

BUT because enums in java are also reference types I do not understand one thing. Let's replace A class by Enum:

```
public static enum TestEnum {
        ONE, TWO, THREE;        
    }

    public static class Test {
        int i;
        TestEnum enumValue;

    public Test(int i, TestEnum enumVar){
        this.i = i;
        this.enumValue = enumVar;  
    }

    public Test(Test oldTest){
        this.i = oldTest.i;
        this.enumValue = oldTest.enumValue;  // WHY IT IS OK ?? 
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t1 = new Test(10, TestEnum.ONE);
    System.out.println(t1.i + " " + t1.enumValue);
    Test t2 = new Test(t1);
    t2.i = 200;
    t2.enumValue = TestEnum.THREE;  // why t1.emunValue != t2.enumValue  ??
    System.out.println(t2.i + " " + t2.enumValue);
    System.out.println(t1.i + " " + t1.enumValue);

}
```

I was expecting output:

```
10 ONE
200 THREE
10 THREE   <--- I thought that reference has been copied... not value
```

But I've got:

```
10 ONE
200 THREE
10 ONE
```

Question: Why? Where my thinking is incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about enums here. You'll see the exact same behaviour if you use strings or *any* type, basically.

Your two `Test` objects are entirely separate. When you write:

```
t2.enumValue = TestEnum.THREE;
```

you're changing the value of the `enumValue` field within the second object to be a reference to the object referred to by `TestEnum.THREE`.

The two `enumValue` fields (one via `t1` and one via `t2`) are entirely separate. Changing one field doesn't change another.

Now, if instead you made your enum mutable (which I would *strongly* discourage) and changed your code to something like this:

```
t2.enumValue.someMutableField = "a different value";
```

... then that *would* be visible via `t1.enumValue`, because they both refer to the same object.

It's really important to differentiate between changing a field within an instance of `Test`, and changing a field within an object that you happen to *reach* via an instance of `Test`.

Again, this really isn't about enums. You may well find it's simpler to get your head round the idea by changing the `enumValue` field to a `String` field, and experimenting that way.